# How to constantly check the value of an SQL row?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a few questions, First of all, here is my code

```
do {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `Started` FROM `verifyAccounts` WHERE `Username` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $Username);
    $stmt->execute();
    sleep(2);
} while (/*VALUE OF `Started`*/ != 0);

if (/*VALUE OF `Started`*/ == 1) {
    echo "Correct";
} elseif (/*VALUE OF `Started`*/ == 2) {
    echo "Incorrect";
}
```

First of all, how can I get the value of `Started` and is there a better more efficient way to check to see what the value of `Started` is?

Comment: Take a look at this: [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Comment: @Tom , So `$stmt->bind_result($StartedValue);` And then `} while ($stmt->fetch() != 0);` makes sense?

Comment: I am not too familiar with `mysqli_*` myself, I use `PDO` which is in my opinion easier. But if this works for you then I it is fine.

Comment: First move the `prepare` to before the `do` - the statement only needs to be prepared once. May I ask why are you checking constantly? i.e. what problem were you originally asked to solve that you decided polling a database was a useful way of doing it? Not saying it isn't a good way. But there are other options that may be more flexible.

Comment: @RyanVincent basically, a user clicks a button on my website, ajax goes to this php page and insert a value of 0 for a specific username. Then, a desktop program runs and does stuff, and then changes it to 1. I want the website to wait until that 1 is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access  `Started` by fetch statement by doing `$stmt->fetch();`

Use `$Started` in place of `/*VALUE OF`Started`*/`

```
do {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `Started` FROM `verifyAccounts` WHERE `Username` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $Username);
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($Started);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    sleep(2);
} while (/*VALUE OF `Started`*/ != 0);

if (/*VALUE OF `Started`*/ == 1) {
    echo "Correct";
} elseif (/*VALUE OF `Started`*/ == 2) {
    echo "Incorrect";
}
```

Comment: What do I replace /*VALUE OF `Started`*/ with to get the actual value of `Started`?